# Including git repo projects into my portfolio

Tags: git, portfolio

I'm currently building my portfolio website. I want to include my personal projects which has their own git repo each. What should be the best approach on doing this? I have a fair amount of knowledge of git, but I wouldn't say I am on an expert level. Should I just use `git-clone` foreach project inside their designated folders in my website/application?

While researching I have found two options for which I have to decide which is the best one to use.

- Using git submodules
- Creating a private package on npm for my personal projects then install it as a dependendency on my website/application

These two are the only options I have come accross with while doing my research, but any additional suggestion on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about putting your git repos on something like GitHub or Gitlab and providing a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option (git submodules) should be used if you want to frequently update your submodules, having the latest version of the source code throughout your final app. Also, your build process will have to rebuild both your submodules as well as your final app in order to have everything built up.

The second option (an npm package) should be used if you don't want to frequently update the versions of your dependencies (submodules in previous option), meaning you want to focus on your final app code and its features, rather than to always rebuild everything, including dependencies (and solving any possible issues/conflicts in the process). This way you can decide when do you want to upgrade your dependencies, by updating their packages and rebuilding your final app, solving any issues if needed.

Both options are valid approaches, you just need to decide what you want for each app you build. The 2nd option is usually a preferred choice for many developers today, since it delays handling the dependencies upgrade conflicts to the point where they are actually ready and willing to do that, instead of being forced to frequently spend time on it, whenever any dependency introduces any kind of a breaking change.